# Determining where a business has its primary listing

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom

How can I determine whether a business has its primary listing in the UK? I could run it through a screener - but how about checking it directly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The details of the stock listing(s) should be described in the company's *prospectus* which is usually available from their Investor Relations department, or investor relations section of their web site.

Some may be multiply listed in different companies, so will not necessarily have a single primary listing.